# is the normal proof of halting problem undecidability is wrong?

Tags: logic, computer-science, computability, turing-machines

The normal proof goes as follows:

if H(f) is a program that takes the source code of any program f and return whether it halts, we define G to be

if(H(G)){
loop forever
}
else {
halt
}
Which is a contradiction if you run H on G.

My problem is the unjustified assertion that a program like G even exists, as presumably it is able to print its own source code and run H on it (or something analogous to that) and halt or not halt based on that. My intuition tells me this violates some information theoretic result I am not smart enough to know about.

Furthermore, since we have no idea what H even looks like, this proof only works if you can prove that for every program P, there exists a program G which can print its own source code, run P on it, and then do some stuff based on that. Since the mere existence of Quines, which still conserve information, is already a deep and complicated result (from what I can tell), the truth of Gs existance is sketchy to say the least.

Comment: That you can always assume a program can print its own source code is a nontrivial result, a consequence of the [recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem). But you don't need to appeal to it, really... in my experience what you wrote down is not the "normal proof"... it looks more like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem#Sketch_of_rigorous_proof).

Comment: Also, the 'sketchiness' is exactly why this sort of results needs to be proved — but those proofs do exist, and in fact they even give a _mechanical_ procedure for producing such a G for any H. These mechanics are the 'boring' bits of the proof and often glossed over, but they have been thoroughly worked out.

Comment: in turing's original paper - there were some inconsistencies in the 3rd part of the proof, where he proves the entschiendung's problem, as later identified by P. Bernays , refer - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing%27s_proof#Complications , although turing gave corrections to them later,..  But the first and second part were basically airtight as far as i understand..... Also turing himself never proposed the word ' halting problem', refer - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem#Origin_of_the_halting_problem